# How can I make this arm accessory?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I want to make some sort of arm accessory/ cover, but I don't know how I should approach it. Here is a reference picture.
[image]

All of them are a cylinder sculpted with multiresolution modifier. Here is what I have:

In the first picture it looks quite close to what I intended but I can't make the holes in it. (because of the sculpting, so I made another one).

[image]

In the 2nd attempt I deleted some faces, but forgot about the holes.
[image]

Here I could make the holes before sculpting the cylinder, but I destroyed them while making it closer to the object I had in mind .... 
[image]

This is the raw cylinder with holes in it..
I've tried using the shrinkwrap modifier but it didn't do the trick for me
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **paint the holes with transparency**. Basically, as you already did.
Bake the normal map from the *Multires* and then texture the accessory.
Use the alpha channel (or create a separate mask image) for *Alpha* slot of the *Principled BSDF* (or use a *Transparent BDSF* and a *MixShader*). Add some metal rings. That's it.

I had made something similar. Looks like this:

Low-poly mesh with rings (low poly circles + *Solidify* and *Subdivision* modifiers)
[image: screenshot1]

Textured with transparency (no baked normal map yet)
[image: screenshot2]

You can even pull a ribbon through the eyelets :-)
[image: screenshot3]
The ribbon is just flat plane with a *Solidify* and *Subdivision* modifier. In fact, it's not one part but several "V" parts.

Comment: wooow thank you! it looks good. i will try this method, hopefully i manage to do it:D !